# Receiving "drivers not found" when loading a .php file containing new PDO

Tags: php, mysql, iis, pdo, iis-7

I recently installed iis 7 and php 5.6.15 on my windows computer and for the most part everything is working fine. I can run phpinfo perfectly, but when I was trying to connect to a remote MySQL database I received the error above.

From searching the web I've learned that I do not have the module required to use pdo (pdo_mysql I think?).

I also for some reason do not have a php.ini. I have a loaded configuration file of (none) according to phpinfo. I have a php.ini-production and development however, but when I renamed production as php.ini I couldn't even use phpinfo.

So in conclusion how would I go about installing the pdo module I need (noting that I have very little experience with web design or php in general)?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a WAMP stack instead of IIS. Use WAMP/XAMPP on your windows! It's much easier to configure, and install modules. Plus, it would have configured your MySQL and Apache Server for php for you! So, you can just start building away!

Comment: So I've heard, but I need to hook into someone else's mysql server remotely and this is what I had at the time.

Comment: Exactly. Instead of finding this module and trying to install it, just see if you can install one of these servers (WAMP/XAMPP) and all those driver issues will go away!

Hooking onto someone else's MySQL can be done, but the php module has to be present first!

Comment: Oh ok. I had thought that they just allowed me to host my own MySQL server. Which one do you suggest?

Comment: Well, you can host you own MySQL server as well, but then you said you want to use a MySQL server online. I personally use WAMP! Try it out.